# rewrite htaccess to https with route

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, https

Im using the following .htaccess for my website. I redirect all urls to index.php if their isn't a file located at the url.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
# Turn on the RewriteEngine
RewriteEngine On
#  Rules
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```

This way http://website.com/user/user_name/ goes to index.php 
and
http://website.com/css/style.css gives the actual css file (if style.css exists).

This works great, only i want to force https:// on the urls and i can't manage to get it to work. Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Edit:**

Using Jeroen's answer I got it working with the following .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
# Turn on the RewriteEngine
RewriteEngine On
#  Rules
RewriteCond %{HTTP:CF-Visitor} '"scheme":"http"'
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you are using CloudFlare's ssl - I assume Flexible SSL - you need a different solution although @Fox's solution is correct for a "normal" ssl connection.

For CloudFlare you need something like:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:CF-Visitor} '"scheme":"http"'
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]
```

Also see [CloudFlare's support article](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170536-How-do-I-redirect-HTTPS-traffic-with-Flexible-SSL-and-Apache-).

Comment: Added this and it worked. Thank you! Can you explain why cloudflare needs this different treatment ?

Comment: @KoenHendriks You don't have a real ssl connection to your server, only from the client to CloudFlare. The connection from CloudFlare to your server is a normal http connection so your original solution does not work. However, CloudFlare adds a http header so that you can check to see if the visitor requested an http or an https connection and that is the CloudFlare `CF-Visitor` header you see in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
  RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: It is sending me to the https but it's giving me a redirect loop.

Comment: @KoenHendriks Are you using CloudFlare's ssl?